# Changing length of Navigation Bar made with CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: My Problem]Is it possible to change the length of a navbar made by CSS? If so, how is it done? Like instead of stretching across the whole page, it stops at a certain distance
Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate the sidebar, aka the distance i need the navbar not to cover http://jsfiddle.net/jAVQv/
Here is the code that I have for the navbar (from *W3Schools* with minor edits):

```
ul.topnav:not(.ignore) {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li:not(.ignore) {float: right;}
ul.topnav li a:not(.ignore) {
display: inline-block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.ignore) {background-color: #555;}
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
ul.topnav li:not(:first-child):not(.ignore) {display: none;}
ul.topnav li.icon:not(.ignore) {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
ul.topnav.responsive:not(.ignore) {position: relative;}
ul.topnav.responsive li.icon:not(.ignore) {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
ul.topnav.responsive li:not(.ignore) {
float: none;
display: inline;
}
ul.topnav.responsive li a:not(.ignore) {
display: block;
text-align: right;
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D My problem is that the navigation bar stretches across the whole web page, and covers the entire "top" part of the web page. (see the header in the JS fiddle) I want it not to cover some area which is depicted as the sidebar

Comment: And what should the fiddle tell us ? In the fiddle the navbar doesn't cover the sidebar. Just change the width of the navbar if you want to change the lenght.

Comment: How would i change the width???